# Web crawling to create a business

Tags: web-crawling, legal

If I were to web crawl supermarkets' websites and retrieve info and create a comparison tool for sale would that be illegal?

Comment: I would highly suggest reading this Quora post on the topic: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-legality-of-web-scraping

Comment: @MarkSilverberg : the data can't be copywritted, if they try to block you, and you attempt to circumvent the block, you might be prosecuted.  (https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/07/court-violating-terms-service-not-crime-bypassing ; http://lifehacker.com/5901773/breaking-a-terms-of-service-isnt-necessarily-a-crime ) ... but even if it's considered legal, that doesn't mean that a [district attorney won't push for prosecution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz#Arrest_and_prosecution).  My suggestion is that if they have a robots.txt or AUP, don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK the Computer Misuse Act from 1990 (section 1) states that it is an offence to access a computer where:

- the access to the data is unauthorised
- the offender knows that it is unauthorised

This may extend to web scraping because, in some circumstances, you are accessing the website intending to use the data in a way that is not authorised by the website owner.

**Thus, the conservative and recommended way is to ask the owner for permission.**